# merging multiple rows into one row per record seprated by a blank line in unix

Tags: unix, awk, sed

I have a text file in which each record starts with a no and name and ends with a blank line. I would like to have per record in one row as comma-separated values. I have tried the following code whose code file and text file link attached below:
[biosample.txt](https://filebin.net/1ssncdgjppffsiso/biosample_result__2_.txt?t=awacukhc)
[sark.awk](https://www.mediafire.com/file/mf6ucv6t7opl4ao/sark.awk/file)

unix command: to run the code is:

```
gawk -f sark.awk biosample.txt
```

then run:

```
sed 's/,,/\n/g' <biosample.txt > out.txt
```

but the `out.txt` is a bit discrepant/messy/confusing.

I want each record in one line with the values to be extracted for the following headers only:

```
record name
Identifiers
Organism
strain
isolate
serovar
isolation source
collected by
collection date
geographic location
host
host disease
Accession
ID
potential_contaminant
sample type
Description
```

Having the values for each header to be picked from each record that is separated by a new line.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post an extract of the input file and what the output file should look like?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show the code and a small input file directly in your question formatted as code blocks. *"discrepant/messy/confusing"* is not a sufficient problem description. Show the actual and expected output and if necessary explain why the actual output is wrong.

Comment: @user3506020 - The indentation of `sark.awk` is ridiculous.

Comment: How can it be that the `gawk` input and the `sed` input, which latter must be the `gawk` output, have the same name `biosample.txt`?

Comment: I have attached my file and code in the post it is downloadable.

Comment: @Armali first run gawk and store gawk output as biosample1.txt and then run sed whose output will be in out.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a straightforward implementation with `awk`:

```
BEGIN   { print "record name,Identifiers,Organism,strain,isolate,serovar,"\
                "isolation source,collected by,collection date,"\
                "geographic location,host,host disease,Accession,ID,"\
                "potential_contaminant,sample type,Description"
          RS="\r\n"
          ORS=""
        }
sub(/^[0-9]*: /,"")     { r[1] = $0; next }
sub(/^Identifiers: /,""){ r[2] = $0; next }
sub(/^Organism: /,"")   { r[3] = $0; next }
/^ /                    { split($0, a, "=") }
/^ *\/strain=/          { r[4] = a[2] }
/^ *\/isolate=/         { r[5] = a[2] }
/^ *\/serovar=/         { r[6] = a[2] }
/^ *\/isolation source=/{ r[7] = a[2] }
/^ *\/collected by=/    { r[8] = a[2] }
/^ *\/collection date=/ { r[9] = a[2] }
/^ *\/geographic locati/{ r[10] = a[2] }
/^ *\/host=/            { r[11] = a[2] }
/^ *\/host disease=/    { r[12] = a[2] }
/^Accession:/           { r[13] = $2; r[14] = $4 }
/^ *\/potential_contami/{ r[15] = a[2] }
/^ *\/sample type=/     { r[16] = a[2] }
/^Description:/         { getline; r[17] = $0 }
/^$/                    { if (r[1]) {   for (i = 1; i < 17; ++i) print r[i]","
                                        print r[i]"\n"
                                        delete r
                                    }
                        }
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH THIS WORKED REALLY WELL